# Converting a lua hex function to use in PHP

Tags: php, lua

The problem that I am facing is I'm trying to send an image via a post request from a lua environment without using Base64. I'm using this function to change the data to something that I can send in a post request.

```
function string.tohex(str)
    return str:gsub('.', function (c)
         return string.format('%02X', string.byte(c))
    end) 
end
```

I can convert it back just fine in lua using.

```
function string.fromhex(str)
    return str:gsub('..', function (cc)
        return string.char(tonumber(cc, 16))
    end)
end
```

For reference this is what the string.tohex returns when I pass the image to it [pastebin.com/4t3LdZWP](http://pastebin.com/4t3LdZWP)

But what I can not figure out how to do is replicate this function in php.

edit This is what I tried doing in php to convert it back

```
preg_replace_callback(
    '..',
    function ($matches) {
        return chr(intval($matches[0], 16));
    },
    $data
);
```

Comment: Have you made an attempt to do so? What was wrong with what you tried?

Comment: I couldn't get anywhere with the code I was trying to write, I'm still relatively new to php and I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Why are you ASCII-encoding it in the first place? It's a POST request. You can send binary data. Send the raw bytes.

Answer (score 0):

The patterns in PHP are a bit different than that of lua! You need to provide delimiters as well:

```
preg_replace_callback(
    '/../',
    function ($matches) {
        return chr(intval($matches[0], 16));
    },
    $data
);
```

Here, `/` acts as delimiter.